# Две модалки с одинаковой логикой

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть две кнопки, по клику на которые срабатывают попапы. Проблема в том, что по нажатию на них поочереди всплывают сразу два попапа, и ломается логика. Что я делаю не так? Думаю, проблема с `bind`, может нельзя два раза использовать ?
Мне нужно чтобы окна открывались по очереди, и одновременно два нельзя было открыть. Кто сможет помочь, подсказать?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    $('.modal-order').hide(300);
    $('.order-btn').click(function (e) {
        var $order = $('.modal-order');

        if ($order.css('display') != 'block') {
            $order.show(300);

            var yourClick = true;
            $(document).bind('click.myEvent', function (e) {
                if (!yourClick && $(e.target).closest('.modal-order').length == 0) {
                    $order.hide(300);
                    $(document).unbind('click.myEvent');
                }
                yourClick = false;
            });
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('.modal-search').hide(300);
    $('.search-btn').click(function (e) {
        var $search = $('.modal-search');

        if ($search.css('display') != 'block') {
            $search.show(300);

            var yourClickSearch = true;
            $(document).bind('click.myEvent', function (e) {
                if (!yourClickSearch && $(e.target).closest('.modal-search').length == 0) {
                    $search.hide(300);
                    $(document).unbind('click.myEvent');
                }
                yourClickSearch = false;
            });
            
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="order-btn" type="button">Click</button>

<button class="search-btn" type="button">Click2</button>

<div class="modal-order">
    <h3>Hello</h3>
</div>

<div class="modal-search">
    <h3>Hello 2</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Никаких попапов в коде не обнаружено. Зато обнаружено два идентичных куска кода. Почитайте эту статью [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Логика ломается из-за анимации, в момент вызова второго попапа анимация первого может еще не завершится, а после завершения анимации стили блока изменятся и перебьют то, что задалось при нажатии на вторую кнопку.

Для анимации используйте функцию **.animate()**, при ее использовании всегда можно узнать происходит ли в момент клика по другой кнопке анимация в первой(псевдоселектор *jquery* **:animated**) и прервать ее **.stop()**.

Использование перечисленного сделает код короче и проще. 
Информация по перечисленным функциям и псевдоселектору есть на сайте: http://api.jquery.com/